# Iphone execute windows dll

Tags: iphone

Is there a way for an iphone app to interact with an windows dll(business logic).
I want to send a request to a web share which has all the dll's and get a response in return. this response can be a pdf or a url.

Is it possible to do this? Or am i trying to do which is not possible?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an asp.net web service that can execute methods in the dll.  The iphone app can call the webservice.  Doing a google search for "iphone asp.net web service" will give lots of ways to do this.